# Is it possible to disable delete all query in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to allow only those `DELETE` queries that have a `WHERE` clause in them?

I've tried to use `RULE` for that, but I can't figure out what to put into it's `WHERE` clause, right now this `RULE` disables all `DELETE` queries:

```
create rule prevent_delete_all  as on DELETE to site 
DO INSTEAD NOTHING
```

**Edit**

Problem with revoking delete access from users and creating stored procedures for calling `DELETE` is that I don't want to re-write application code that is using the DB

Comment: Consider: Revoking delete access on the table for most accounts, and only allow though stored procedure with required parameters for a where clause?   Problem with just checking for a where clause is `where 1=1` still deletes all

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe the conditions to a `Rule` only apply to actual data and not in the general sense of if `x` clause such as a `WHERE` clause exists. I don't think this is the right format for your solution. But having said that, I would be interested to see a solution from others (seems like a handy know-how to have)

Comment: @xQbert that might be a workaround, but will require a lot of changes on the application level, I was hoping to implement this on the DB level, so that it won't affect the applications

Comment: @RevXaisks yeah, I haven't found a where to specify the correct `where` clause for the rule

Comment: lol, don't delete this post, I'm going to link it from my [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern) collection.

Comment: @danihp and what's the right pattern for this anti-pattern? :) btw, would be nice if you share the link to it

Comment: hi @VsevolodGoloviznin, sorry it's a private collection ;) Only for my eyes. What are you looking for with this bizarre behavior? What is the underlying problem?

Comment: `Delete from students where 1=1;`

Comment: @danihp the way to prevent `delete from tbl` query, without heavy modifications to applications using the DB

Comment: @joop that's merely a fail-safe against `delete from tbl` queries and the 'human factor' behind it

Comment: You could write an extension to do this with an `ExecutorStart_hook` if you're good at C. It'll break lots of applications that expect to be able to `delete from sometable;` though.

Comment: Given my first approach didn't cut mustard... How about... Write a trigger which calls a procedure that checks the number of rows effected before the commit and if the commit is equal to the row count then rollback the delete.  Put another way: Count # of rows in table before delete.  execute the delete but don't commit.  Count # of rows effected by delete.  If count = delete count rollback.  Though this could be expensive if it's a large table.

Comment: @xQbert the first approach looks interesting, I'll give it a shot tomorrow!

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin don't forget your old friend "truncate" either, depending on your application you may need to protect somehow against abuse/misuse of that too !

Comment: @xQbert, it may be more efficient to just let delete do its work, don't commit yet; check if there `exists` at least one row after delete, if not - rollback. `exists` is often more efficient, than `count`.

Answer (score -1):

As discussed in the comments, requiring a WHERE clause in all delete statements isn't going to help much. The problem is that the user can always declare a WHERE clause that is always true - for example:

```
Delete from students where 1=1;
```

I've tried to detect clauses like this before - and they can be arbitrarily complex so consistently detecting them is very hard, if not impossible.

Instead, I would suggest that you reconsider what it is that you are trying to do. Some alternatives might be: keep a record of all changes to the table by versioning the data, or disallow deleting any rows and just modify the application to mark rows as deleted by adding a 'Deleted' column.

Comment: The main idea behind the question is to prevent from accidental data removal (when you 'forgot' to add a WHERE clause to delete operation and press execute) whereas intentional data removal is not the case. Anyway thanks for the answer :)