# How to disable delete and update query in pgadmin4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I want to disable all delete and update queries. I tried [Is it possible to disable delete all query in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270443/is-it-possible-to-disable-delete-all-query-in-postgres) but hit the following error on PostgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  relation "site" does not exist 

SQL state: 42P01
```

How to create a new user in pgadmin4 and assign it `pg_read_all_data` role? https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6982

Comment: The question you linked was never answered, as what it was trying to accomplish (requiring a WHERE clause for DELETE statements) isn't something PG can do without using, eg, stored procedures. So the first question is, what are you trying to accomplish? Are you sure the question you linked is trying to do the same thing you are?

Comment: 1) For Postgres 14+ use the `pg_read_all_data` role as defined here [Pre-defined roles](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/predefined-roles.html). Assign that role to the users/roles. 2) Postgres != pgAdmin4. pgAdmin4 is just a client. You need to be more clear about where you want the disabling to take place.

Comment: I want to disable all delete and update queries.

Comment: Do you want to prevent a particular user from modifying particular tables? Or do you want to prevent *anyone* from modifying those tables?

Comment: A user. Specifically a pgadmin4 user, without creating a new user in the postgreSQL database.

Comment: How to create a new user in pgadmin4 and assign it `pg_read_all_data` role? https://github.com/pgadmin-org/pgadmin4/issues/6982

Comment: @KokHowTeh You want a PgAdmin user which cannot run delete nor update queries on *any* database? I don't know if that's possible, nor effective. What is the purpose?

Comment: The purpose is for users from business to be able to view but not edit or accidentally edit the DB.....

Comment: @KokHowTeh For that, [revoke](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-revoke/) the privileges on their roles of their Postgres users on the server. PgAdmin is just a client.

Answer (score 1):

> *The purpose is for users from business to be able to view but not edit or accidentally edit the DB*

What you're looking for is [privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html). These can control which user is allowed to do what to which objects (tables, schemas, sequences, functions are all objects). The command to remove privileges is [`revoke`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-revoke.html).

This is something you do to their roles on the database. PgAdmin is just a client that talks to the database. If you were able to block the queries in just PgAdmin people could just use a different client.

The privileges you're looking for are `delete` and `update`, and probably also `truncate`. It would look something like this...

```
revoke delete, update, truncate 
on all tables in schema your_schema
from your_user
```

The details depend on how your schema and privileges are set up.

See also [PostgreSQL REVOKE at postgresqltutorial.com](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-administration/postgresql-revoke/)

Comment: Not good. You can only revoke privileges that were granted. So you'd have to examine the privileges first. Perhaps the privileges were granted to a different role or to `PUBLIC`.